# Order by more than one column with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The below shown is my query I need to **order by** with these three columns . This is for complex search listing. If I used one of them ,it works perfectly . But handling more than one ,it does not order properly.

**EDIT**

Actually I needed ,premium records must be at first positions along with more favorites , and also elite customers have more priority .
These all works conditionally

1) More favorites will come at first

2) But premium will be considered

3) If basic will have 5 favorites ,it wont push to top ,basic having small priority

4) As well elite have some good priority

```
SELECT  
   `Driver`.`id` ,  
   `Driver`.`login_id` ,  
   `Login`.`profile_type`, 
   .................
ORDER BY  `fav_count`, 
   FIELD(  `Login`.`profile_type` ,  "premium",  "basic" ) ,  
   `Driver`.`is_elite` ASC
```

**Sample result I expected**

```
is_elite|       profile_type  | fav_count
________|_____________________|____________
1       |        premium      |   4      
1       |        premium      |   3 
1       |        premium      |   2 
1       |        premium      |   1 
0       |        basic        |   5 
0       |        basic        |   0
```

Please advise me . Thanks

Comment: Please make your question more readable.

Comment: Hello All I've edited my question

Comment: I can see at least 10 different orderings that give the same result as your sample. Please clarify with more data, that have same/different data in `profile_type` and/or `is_elite` columns.

Comment: Again edited question , please read all 3 are linked together

Comment: Let me ask a couple of questions to help clarify... Is a Premium profile always elite?  If not, please add a row to your example that illustrates the sorting when this is not the case.  Second, is "fav_count" actually a count or is it a ranking?  I'm not sure this matters, since "fav_count" seems to be your least important sort column.

Comment: @JerseyMike Yes fav_count is just a count of how many favorite votes for one driver

Comment: @duke, and is a premium profile always elite?  If not, please add a row to your example that indicates how that would be sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the output you listed, you need to reorder the values in the ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY `Driver`.`is_elite` DESC, FIELD(  `Login`.`profile_type` ,  "premium",  "basic" ) DESC, `fav_count` DESC
```

Note: You also need to have descending (DESC) on all of your sort columns.  Each of them is being sorted largest to smallest.

Comment: By the way, I am assuming that "is_elite" has more precedence than "profile_type", sort-wise. If that's not true, put "profile_type" first in the ORDER BY list and "is_elite" second.

Comment: @duke, here is how to build your ORDER BY... #1: Pick the field that is most important (sorting-wise) and add it to the list.  #2: If it should be sorted with the largest values first, add "DESC".  #3: Go back to #1 until you are out of sort columns.  If you follow those rules, you should get what you want.

Answer (score 5):

unsure of your question, but this gives the order you show in the example.

```
order by profile_type desc, fav_count desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the ORDER BY something like this:

```
ORDER BY `table`.`is_elite`, `table`.`profile_type`, `table`.`fav_count` DESC
```

This will order in the way that you expect (as far as i can see from the code you have given).

Answer (score 0):

From the sample result you expected it looks like you wanted to use:

```
ORDER BY  FIELD(  `Login`.`profile_type` ,  "premium",  "basic" ), `fav_count` DESC,  `Driver`.`is_elite` ASC
```

But this is speculative at best, your question wasn't worded very well.