# php/mysql multiple order by

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a results table at the minute, I am wanting to sort a table, by points (highest at the top), if points are equal I want to sort by goal difference, and then if goal difference is equal I want to sort by goals scored.

So a table may look like this,

```
+--------+--------+----------+-----------------+--------+
|  Team  | Scored | Conceded | Goal Difference | Points |
+--------+--------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| Team A |     20 |       10 | +10             |     15 |
| Team B |     20 |       15 | +5              |     15 |
| Team C |     10 |       10 | 0               |      9 |
| Team D |      5 |       5  | 0               |      9 |
+--------+--------+----------+-----------------+--------+
```

So Team A wins the league because it has a better goal difference than Team B, Team C finish above Team D because they score more goals, and all other things are equal.

Is it possible to order this way in mysql, or will I need to parse the results with PHP?

Comment: No, you don't need PHP. There's more SQL than `SELECT * FROM tablename`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order by more than one column with mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889403/order-by-more-than-one-column-with-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

Guess what, you can pass multiple column names to ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY Points DESC, `Goal Difference` DESC, Scored DESC
```

You haven't given your table structure, but as pointed out by [jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5960800/jpg) if these fields are not numeric, ORDER by field_name + 0 may be more appropriate

Comment: You've forgot about Points ;)

Comment: In case that `Goal Difference` may be `char` or `varchar`, `\`Goal Difference\` + 0` will be better. :-D

Comment: Agreed @JPG but you know how these fastest gun of the west answers are shoot first edit later :) but there were a couple of others that needed shooting :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this using query

```
SELECT * from `your_table` ORDER BY points DESC, goal_difference DESC, scored DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by multiple columns at the same time.

```
SELECT some_cols
FROM table
WHERE (some conditions)
ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2, col3;
```